# Is it possible to have two labels for an axis using Show function?

Tags: plotting

I use this code

```
P1 := RegionPlot[0 <= Cos[y x] <= 1/2, {y, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> LightBlue, 
  FrameLabel -> {{Style[Rotate["F", 270 Degree], 15], 
     None}, {Style["y", 15], None}}, BaseStyle -> 15]

P2 := RegionPlot[0 <= Cos[-y x] <= 1/2, {y, 0, 3}, {x, 0, -5}, 
  PlotStyle -> LightBlue, 
  FrameLabel -> {{Style[Rotate["G", 270 Degree], 15], 
     None}, {Style["y", 15], None}}, BaseStyle -> 15]


Show[{P1, P2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

and the result is

[image]

But here, it only shows one of the FrameLabel; Is it possible to ask Mathematica to give both labels **using `Show`**? We can do it by other commands, but this is not my original function, and I want to know is it possible to do it **by using `Show`** or not? like this

[image]

Comment: One way to get there is `Show[{P1, P2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {{Style[Rotate["F\n\n\n\n\n\nG", 270 Degree], 15, 
     Bold], None}, {Style["y", 15], None}}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
P1 = RegionPlot[0 <= Cos[y x] <= 1/2, {y, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> LightBlue, 
   FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {Style["y", 15], None}}, 
   BaseStyle -> 15];

P2 = RegionPlot[0 <= Cos[-y x] <= 1/2, {y, 0, 3}, {x, 0, -5}, 
   PlotStyle -> LightBlue];
```

You can add the labels using the options [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html), [`PlotRangeClipping`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping.html) and [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html):

```
Show[P1, P2, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> {Text[Style["F", 15], {-.15, 3}], 
   Text[Style["G", 15], {-.15, -3}]},  
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> {{50, 5}, {50, 5}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html) to add the labels:

```
Legended[Show[P1, P2, PlotRange -> All], 
 {Placed[Style["F", 15], {0, .82}], Placed[Style["G", 15], {0, .3}]}]
```

[image]